# Прыжок во время спринта

Tags: c#, unity3d

Вообщем-то проблема в том что при прыжке и спринте одновременно скорость передвижения не изменеятся( Код в придачу ).

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


[RequireComponent(typeof(CharacterController))]
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {

    public float walkSpeed = 3.0f;
    public float sprintSpeed = 30.0f;
    public float jumpForce = 10.0f;
    public float fallSpeed = 30.0f;

    [HideInInspector] public float deltaX = 0.0f;
    [HideInInspector] public float deltaY = 0.0f;
    [HideInInspector] public float deltaZ = 0.0f;

    private float _currentSpeed;
    private bool _isGrounded = false;

    private CharacterController _character = null;

    private void Awake()
    {
        Initialize();
        Cursorlock();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        OnCheckGrounded();
        OnMove();
        OnJump();
        OnBakeMovement();
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
        _character = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    private void OnCheckGrounded()
    {
        Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, -transform.up);
        RaycastHit hit;
        float distanceToHit = 1.1f;
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, distanceToHit))
        {
            _isGrounded = true;
        }
        else
        {
            _isGrounded = false;
        }
    }

    private void OnMove()
    {
        _currentSpeed = walkSpeed;

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            _currentSpeed = sprintSpeed;
        }
        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            _currentSpeed = sprintSpeed / 100;
        }

        deltaX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * _currentSpeed;
        deltaZ = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * _currentSpeed;
    }

    private void OnJump()
    {
        if (_isGrounded == true)
        {
            deltaY = 0.0f;
            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
            {
                deltaY = jumpForce;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            deltaY -= fallSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }

    private void OnBakeMovement()
    {
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(deltaX, 0.0f, deltaZ);
        movement = transform.TransformVector(movement);
        movement = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(movement, _currentSpeed);
        movement.y = deltaY;
        movement *= Time.deltaTime;

        _character.Move(movement);
    }

    private void Cursorlock()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В двух разных методах проверяешь на прыжок? Не легче в одном сделать  Возможно ошибка кроется именно в этом

Comment: Пробовал уже, не помогло.

Comment: У вас при каждом вызове `OnMove` скорость приравнивается 3.0f, а вызывается он частенько)

Comment: Даже если я его поставлю в OnBakeMovement() или в OnJump() то та самая ошибка у меня остается.

Answer (score 0):

Вы используйте проверку нажатия где доминирует первое условие **LeftShift** нажатие, потому что она нажата в двух случаях, и в большинстве случаев всегда будет именно она работать, и лишь на короткое время пока была нажата **Jump** и **LeftShift** придерживается выполняется второе условие. И снова переходиться к первому условиему.

Предлагаю делать проверку что при зажатой **LeftShift** Вы находится на земле, или другой удобный способ проверки.

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) && OnCheckGrounded()) {
    _currentSpeed = sprintSpeed;
}
if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift)) {
    _currentSpeed = sprintSpeed / 100;
}
```

Comment: Вызывается очень часто поэтому при нажатии на Jump _currentSpeed возвращает на walkSpeed, а условие действует один кадр и думаю поэтому не получалось.

Comment: @YellowDollar это я и описал выше, был рад если смог помочь Вам. Мой вариант ответа Вам не подошёл?

Comment: Помог конечно, но когда проверяешь нажата ли была кнопка Jump и зажат ли Shift, опять же при прыжке _currentSpeed сразу возвращал walkSpeed а не sprintSpeed / 5 к примеру.(Возможно возвращался но всего лишь на кадр который было не видно)

Answer (score 0):

Исправилось таким образом

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) && _isGrounded == true)
    {
        _currentSpeed = sprintSpeed;
    }
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) && _isGrounded == false)
    {
        _currentSpeed = 10.0f;
    }
```